# Order of string replacement function invocations

Tags: javascript, regex

When calling [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a *replacement function* we're able to retrieve offsets of the matched substrings.

```
var a = [];
"hello world".replace(/l/g, function (m, i) { a.push(i); });
// a = [2, 3, 9]
```

In the example above, we're getting a list of offsets for the matching `l` characters.

Can I count on implementations to always invoke the match function in ascending order of occurrence? That is: Can I be sure that the result above will always be `[2,3,9]` and not `[3,9,2]` or any other permutation of those offsets?

I've looked at the specification and I cannot find anything that specifies the order of invocation, but perhaps this is implied by how the regular expression engine is supposed to be implemented?

Comment: you're sequentially pushing an index into an array while you're parsing the string from the first character to the last one, so yes, the order won't change (and until you don't play with the lastIndex property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Comment: I think it will, but to make sure you can just `sort` next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I count on implementations to always invoke the match function in ascending order of occurrence?

Absolutely, yes. Matches are handled from left to right in the source string because left-to-right is how regular expression engines work their way to a string.

Comment: Also, the regex matching algorithm is formally specified, so it will work the same in all cases.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure: Is this true even when used in an environment primarily configured for languages written from right to left?

Comment: @Mårten That's a good question and actually I think you should ask that as a separate question here on SO. RTL text definitely changes how JavaScript regular expressions behave.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905376/order-of-string-replacement-function-invocations-when-used-with-rtl-languages

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't worry about it. Also you can use the [`Fookahead`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) pattern, which going from the start of the string:

```
"hello world".replace(/(?=l)/g, function (m, i) { a.push(i); });
```